# Highcharts: Exporting.js add two extra button

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I added exporting.js to my project, but when I checked the page it seems to add two extra buttons, but in my jsfiddle it does not, do you have any idea of what is causing this?

This is a diagram of my chart, can you see there are two buttons:

[image]

[image]

This is my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pLDeq/10/

```
exporting: {
            enabled: true,
            exportButton: {
                enabled: true
            },
            buttons: 
            {
                customButton:
                {
                    //x: 20,
                     symbol: 'url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/16/chart_bar.png)',
                    onclick: function() {
                        setChartColumn([name,name2], categories, [data,data2], ['column','column']); 
                    }
                }
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  There are two buttons in your jsFiddle; the first redraws the charts, the second is the standard export button.

Comment: In my project appears two extra buttons (the images), but in my jsFiddle looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, the problem was in the theme, I just remove this lines.

```
 exporting: {
        buttons: {
            exportButton: {
                symbolFill: '#55BE3B'
            },
            printButton: {
                symbolFill: '#7797BE'
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Pls help. How to add more than one button?( if required 3/4 buttons).